# What is the runtime for this particular algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime, big-o

I am thinking this particular code is (log n)^2 because each findindex function takes logn depth and we are calling it logn times? Can someone confirm this? 
I hope one of you can think of this as a small quiz and help me with it.

> Given a sorted array of n integers that has been rotated an unknown
>   number of times, write code to find an element in the array. You may
>   assume that the array was originally sorted in increasing order.

```
# Ex
# input find 5 in {15,16,19,20,25,1,3,4,5,7,10,14}
# output 8
# runtime(log n)


def findrotation(a, tgt):
    return findindex(a, 0, len(a)-1, tgt, 0)


def findindex(a, low, high, target, index):
    if low>high:
        return -1

    mid = int((high + low) / 2)

    if a[mid] == target:
        index = index + mid
        return index
    else:
        b = a[low:mid]
        result = findindex(b, 0, len(b)-1, target, index)
        if result == -1:
            index = index + mid + 1
            c = a[mid+1:]
            return findindex(c, 0, len(c)-1, target, index)
        else:
            return result
```

Comment: `findindex` performs a slice operation `a[low:mid]` which is O(mid-low) time, so it's at least O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm is supposed to be `O(logn)` but is not from implementation perspectives.

- In your algorithm, you're not making decision either to go for left subarray or right subarray only, you're trying with both subarray which is `O(N)`.
- You're doing slicing on array `a[low:mid]` and `a[mid + 1:]` which is `O(n)`.

Which makes your overall complexity `O(n^2)` in worst case.

Assuming there is no duplicates in the array, an ideal implementation in Python 3 of `O(logn)` binary search looks like this -

```
A=[15,16,19,20,25,1,3,4,5,7,10,14]
low = 0
hi = len(A) - 1


def findindex(A, low, hi, target):
    if low > hi:
        return -1
    mid = round((hi + low) / 2.0)
    if A[mid] == target:
        return mid
    if A[mid] >= A[low]:
        if target < A[mid] and target >= A[low]:
            return findindex(A, low, mid - 1, target)
        else : 
            return findindex(A, mid + 1, hi, target)

    if A[mid] < A[low]:
        if target < A[mid] or target >= A[low]:
            return findindex(A, low, mid - 1, target)
        else :
            return findindex(A, mid + 1, hi, target)

    return -1

print(findindex(A, low, hi, 3))
```

Comment: The input array is correct. The question specifies that he has rotated a sorted array. This algorithm uses binary search for finding an element in a rotated sorted array.

Comment: Ops. I missed that, edited now. Thanks for pointing out, please check again :)

Comment: I don't understand your answer: in your function `findindex` how are you supposed to specify which number to find?

Comment: @ChatterOne Sorry, I tried to find minimum element, now edited. Please check again :)

Comment: You probably haven't run your code, because `&&` and `||` should be `and` and `or`. You should also specify that this only works with python 3, because of the floating point division in python 2.